# Mac OS X UNIX-oriented Tutorial

Tags: command-line, unix

Is there any Mac OS X tutorial/book that covers the UNIX part of this operating system? Topics like:

- Managing daemons from the command-line
- Package management
- Install/Remove dmg's from the command-line
- Environment variables
- Users/Groups/Permissions management
- CLI utilities
- OS Directory structure
- Location of dev headers, libraries, etc
- Devices names

Most of the tutorials I found out there cover GUI applications and that kind of stuff. Is there any material that covers Mac OS X under the hood?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to try:
[Unix for OS X](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025870.do) which is a good way to begin with Unix and with the Unix command line interface of Mountain Lion.
O'Reilly is a very good editor in the field of the Unixes environments.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite broad. To get the information you seek in different areas and varied levels of detail, you would have to consult:

- Start with a **FreeBSD** book or tutorial, plus use the `man` command to get information on commands.
- **Apple Pro Training** Material, like the ones mentioned at [OS X and OS X Server training](http://training.apple.com/osx) - this includes paid books/videos published by Peachpit as well as free downloadable guides and white papers by Apple. There is *a lot of material* available from Apple Pro Training.
- A look at the command line section in the [OS X Server: Advanced Administration](http://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.8/#) guide (this may seem a bit shallow if you know Unix and/or have worked with OS X on the command line).
- Some older (and somewhat outdated) books like *Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach* by  Amit Singh, and *Mac OS X and iOS Internals: To the Apple's Core* by Jonathan Levin. These are not for the faint of heart, especially the one by Amit Singh.